# Get key value pair from JSON string

Tags: c#, json, windows

I have a json string like

```
{
  [
    "EnrityList": "Attribute",
    "KeyName": "AkeyName",
    "Value": "Avalue"
  ],
  [
    "EnrityList": "BusinessKey",
    "KeyName": "AkeyName",
    "Value": "Avalue"
  ]
}
```

I have serialized and got an object array.
Could anyone help me to get the key value pair from these object array.

Comment: This isn't valid JSON object. You may use [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/) to check this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JsonConvert` from [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) to deserialize json into Dictionary.

```
Dictionary<string, object> values = 
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(jsonstring);
```

Comment: It works for dictionary not for KeyValuePair Will edit my answer

Comment: `jsonstring` from question contains an invalid JSON. How can this work?

Answer (score 0):

First convert the above string in proper json format by using :

```
str=str.Replace('[', '{');
str=str.Replace(']', '}');
//replace first occurance of {
int startPos = str.IndexOf('{');
str=str.Substring(0,startPos)+" ["+str.Substring(startPos + 1);
//replace last occurance of }
int endPos = str.LastIndexOf('}');
str=str.Substring(0,endPos)+"]";
```

This makes the string

```
str = [{"EnrityList":"Attribute","KeyName":"AkeyName","Value":"Avalue"}, {"EnrityList":"BusinessKey","KeyName":"AkeyName","Value":"Avalue"} ]
```

Now, since you got the json string, you can easily work with it.
  we can use method as given by

[How can I deserialize JSON to a simple Dictionary<string,string> in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207731/how-can-i-deserialize-json-to-a-simple-dictionarystring-string-in-asp-net)

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in myDictionary)
{
    // do something with entry.Value or entry.Key
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Looking at your example, You are trying to receive a List of certain type of elements,
So First, You will need a class to represent your data type.

```
class MyType
{    
  string  EnrityList;
  string  KeyName;
  string  Value;    
}
```

Then use DesrializeObject method to store it in the variable

```
var values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyType>>(jsonstring);
```

Comment: It will work for sure, We use many such things. Did you test?

Comment: `jsonstring` from question contains an invalid JSON. How can this work?

Comment: THat's right, I have suggested an edit, op has messed up with the braces.

Comment: And even though, there is asked to get key-value pairs, not `List`

Comment: I don't think there is a way to get a key-value pair out of it, Json Desrialization will only work with types that follow the same paradigm. This is a JSON array. It can be converted to KeyValuePair if had only two members (Key,Value). Otherwise you need to write your own type, or you need linq or a Conversion in loop.

Comment: Actualy, any object that is deserialized with `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject()` is a `JObject` at first. Which in turn is a `Dictionary<string, object>`. For ex.: `{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}` can be easily deserialized with `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,int>>()` without any custom behaviors.